# getopt() in VC++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008

I'm quite fond of using GNU [**getopt**](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Getopt.html), when programming under **Linux**. I understand, that getopt(), is not available under MS VC++.

**Note:**

- Win32 environment
- using Visual Studio
- No [Boost](http://www.boost.org/)
- No MFC
- Not concerned with portability

**Question:**

- How can I then port getopt() accordingly?

  - What guidelines should I be aware of while porting?
- Known port with **same** features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to check out the license requirements, but the source to the GCC libraries is freely available. Just grab getopt() from there.

Comment: given the constraints on the OPs project, i'm guessing his usage isn't compatible with glibc's license..

Answer (score 6):

This may help, it's also very easy to integrate

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/xgetopt.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is some old code originally by IBM that is available as-is. It only has implementation for getopt, not the _long variants.
It's available on http://plexfx.org/news/files/70411c2c371bd686273a8bebc42c45c5-3.html